# Firestore - Database limitation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting a project with Cloud Firestore and I added my first collections and documents.

In order to be sure to use the right tool, I tried to search if there were limitations with Cloud Firestore.
I saw there were some limitations in bandwidth, number of commits etc.. but I didn't find (or didn't understand) if there was a limitation with the size of the database (number of collections / documents).

Is there a limitation? If yes, does it exist plans/bundles to extend those limitations ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore scales effortlessly.  It will store as much data as you're willing to put into it (and pay for).  Practically speaking, volume of data is not a concern.